# How to connect this js code to the external sheet and connect to the html?

Tags: javascript, html

I have obfuscated an email address using Hiveware Enkoder. The result is below.

[obfuscated code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3mYL.jpg)

I usually place it inside the div just as is.

But I would prefer to include it in an external file and create less text in my code. I know how to copy it properly to a sheet and place the path and syntax in the head, but I do not know how to connect the file to the div where it should function.

Thank you for any help.

/Pat

Answer (score 0):

Making a bunch of assumptions here (because we can't see what your code does and transcribing a picture of text back to text in order to decode it would be far more effort then I'm willing to put in):

You seem to be operating under the misapprehension that using a `src` attribute for a `script` instead of inlining it requires that you place the script in the `head`.

That is not the case. If your script inserts content into the DOM at the point of the `script` element, then just put the script element where you want the content.

Comment: Hi Quentin, I could not figure out how to format the code properly in my question so as to produce it in my question. Stack kept giving me formatting errors, I could not get it right so I resorted to an image after a half hour, sorry. But thank you for taking a minute.

All that does is obfuscate <a href="mailto:myhiddenemail@email.com">This is the link text</a>. The browser shows it as the html would. That's all.

I am just hoping to have a small piece of code in the html and invoke the javascript obfuscation with an external file.

Thanks. /Pat